# The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have added document library template using VS 2012. and then added custom content types to this library. the content types includes 3 managed metadata fields. After deploying the project when I add terms to taxonomy fields in document library, I got following error:

"The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields"

I could not find any solution. Any body have an idea whats wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

IF everything has been setup properly:

- Added an extra note field to the schema.xml for each Taxonomy field
- Changed the throttling settings

AND everything stated in this article is clear and okey-dokey:

http://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/fix-the-splistitem-being-updated-was-not-retrieved-with-all-taxonomy-fields/

then I would suggest to check this:

- open site collection content type using SharePoint Web Interface:
- site settings
- site content types
- open the content type
- In the Columns list open the column giving the error
- Modify site column
- Edit the term set column setting
- save